# Laravel Вывод новостей в цикле в разные блоки

Tags: foreach, laravel-5.6

Пару часов мучаюсь ни как не могу сообразить. имеется макет из 3 дивов в которые в цикле должны выводиться новости[image: макет]

Вопрос собственно вот в чем: как в цикле foreach вывести РАЗНЫЕ новости в разные блоки. Сейчас естественно выводиться одна и та же новость во все блоки

код контроллера

```
public function news() {
    $news = News::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->paginate(3);
    return view('pages.news')->with('news', $news);
  }
```

вьюха

```
@foreach ($news as $new)
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
            <div class="card mb-4 news-block-big">
              <div class="view overlay zoom">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="{{URL::asset($new->img_main)}}" alt="Card image cap">
                <a href="{{url('news/'.$new->id)}}">
                  <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body p-3">
                    <small class="float-right">Дата: {{ $new->created_at }}</small>
                <a href="{{url('news/'.$new->id)}}" class=""><h2 class="card-title pt-4 black-text">{{ $new->title }}</h2></a>
                <p class="card-text">{{ $new->title_small }}<a href="{{url('news/'.$new->id)}}" class=""> читать далее...</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="card mb-4 news-block-small">
                  <div class="view overlay zoom">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{URL::asset($new->img_main)}}" alt="Card image cap">
                    <a href="{{url('news/'.$new->id)}}">
                      <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-body p-3">
                        <small class="float-right">Дата: {{ $new->created_at }}</small>
                    <a href="{{url('news/'.$new->id)}}" class=""><h2 class="card-title pt-4 black-text">{{ $new->title }}</h2></a>
                    <p class="card-text">{{ $new->title_small }}<a href="{{url('news/'.$new->id)}}" class=""> читать далее...</a></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card mb-4 news-block-small">
                  <div class="view overlay zoom">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{URL::asset($new->img_main)}}" alt="Card image cap">
                    <a href="{{url('news/'.$new->id)}}">
                      <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-body p-3">
                        <small class="float-right">Дата: {{ $new->created_at }}</small>
                    <a href="{{url('news/'.$new->id)}}" class=""><h2 class="card-title pt-4 black-text">{{ $new->title }}</h2></a>
                    <p class="card-text">{{ $new->title_small }}<a href="{{url('news/'.$new->id)}}" class=""> читать далее...</a></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{{ $news->links() }}
@endforeach
```

Сейчас делаю так

```
@php
    $k = 0;
@endphp
@foreach ($news as $new)
@switch($k)
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
        @case(0)
        <div class="card mb-4 news-block-big">
          <div class="view overlay zoom">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="{{URL::asset($new->img_main)}}" alt="Card image cap">
            <a href="{{url('news/'.$new->id)}}">
              <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body p-3">
                <small class="float-right">Дата: {{ $new->created_at }}</small>
            <a href="{{url('news/'.$new->id)}}" class=""><h2 class="card-title pt-4 black-text">{{ $new->title }}</h2></a>
            <p class="card-text">{{ $new->title_small }}<a href="{{url('news/'.$new->id)}}" class=""> ...читать далее</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        @php
            $k++;
        @endphp
        @break
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                @case(1)
                <div class="card mb-4 news-block-small">
                  <div class="view overlay zoom">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{URL::asset($new->img_main)}}" alt="Card image cap">
                    <a href="{{url('news/'.$new->id)}}">
                      <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-body p-3">
                        <small class="float-right">Дата: {{ $new->created_at }}</small>
                    <a href="{{url('news/'.$new->id)}}" class=""><h2 class="card-title pt-4 black-text">{{ $new->title }}</h2></a>
                    <p class="card-text">{{ $new->title_small }}<a href="{{url('news/'.$new->id)}}" class=""> ...читать далее</a></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                @php
                    $k++;
                @endphp
                @break

                @case(2)
                <div class="card mb-4 news-block-small">
                  <div class="view overlay zoom">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{URL::asset($new->img_main)}}" alt="Card image cap">
                    <a href="{{url('news/'.$new->id)}}">
                      <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-body p-3">
                        <small class="float-right">Дата: {{ $new->created_at }}</small>
                    <a href="{{url('news/'.$new->id)}}" class=""><h2 class="card-title pt-4 black-text">{{ $new->title }}</h2></a>
                    <p class="card-text">{{ $new->title_small }}<a href="{{url('news/'.$new->id)}}" class=""> ...читать далее</a></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                @php
                    $k++;
                @endphp
                @break
                @endswith
                @if ($k >= 2)
                    @php
                        $k = 0;
                    @endphp
                @else
                @php
                    $k++;
                @endphp
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="offset-5">
    {{ $news->links() }}
</div>

@endforeach
```

и лара выдает синтаксическую ошибку

```
syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting endswitch (T_ENDSWITCH) or case (T_CASE) or default (T_DEFAULT)"
```

Comment: У тебя цикл открывается и закрывается после всех трёх блоков. С таким ещё не сталкивался, но предполагаю что если у тебя на странице три новости то ты можешь не использовать foreach. Просто по индексу $news[0], $news[1], $news[2] выводить в разные блоки.

Comment: Так можно выводить когда записей всего 3, но что делать если их 300?

Comment: Самый простой вариант - завести дополнительную переменную перед foreach, например $k=0. Перед выводом новостей:
switch($k){
   case 0:
    //выводишь первый блок
   case 1:
//выводишь второй блок
case 2:
//выводишь третий блок
}

После вывода одной новости:
($k >= 2) ? $k=0 : $k++

Comment: Это не работает, выводит все также одну новость во все блоки. Можно ли делать что-то вроде этого `{{ $new[i+1]->created_at }}` ?

Comment: Должно работать. Код скинь) `<?php $k=0 ?> 
<?php foreach($news as $new): ?>
<?php switch($k): ?>
<?php case 0: ?>
/* здесь твой вид */
<?php break; ?>
<?php  case 1:?>
/* здесь твой вид*/
<?php break;?>
<?php endswitch; ($k >= 2) ? $k=0 : $k++ ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
`
Можешь писать использовать шаблонизатор вместо <?php ?>, мне так удобнее.

Comment: Выше добавил изменения. Ошибку сейчас выдает

Comment: Да и решение честно говоря костыльное( хочется более элегантного решения

Comment: Пока других вариантов не вижу) Ты не должен инкрементировать после каждого case, это делается в конце switch. Что за ошибку выдаёт ? + case должен быть перед колонкой, если всё красиво оформить, то оно и глаз резать не будет..

Comment: Спасибо! В принципе получилось, выводятся разные новости в разные блоки, но с макетом не как не могу совладать((( все стало в один столбик, то есть сверху 8кол под ним 4кол и ниже еще 4кол.

Comment: Все сделал) спасибо!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал через foreach и switch. Все работает. Владислал огромное спасибо!!

```
@foreach ($news as $new)

@switch($k)
    @case(0)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8">
            <div class="card mb-4 news-block-big">
              <div class="view overlay zoom">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="{{URL::asset($new->img_main)}}" alt="Card image cap">
                <a href="{{url('news/'.$new->id)}}">
                  <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body p-3">
                    <small class="float-right">Дата: {{ $new->created_at }}</small>
                <a href="{{url('news/'.$new->id)}}" class=""><h2 class="card-title pt-4 black-text">{{ $new->title }}</h2></a>
                <p class="card-text">{{ $new->title_small }}<a href="{{url('news/'.$new->id)}}" class=""> ...читать далее</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @break

    @case(1)
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="card mb-4 news-block-small">
                  <div class="view overlay zoom">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{URL::asset($new->img_main)}}" alt="Card image cap">
                    <a href="{{url('news/'.$new->id)}}">
                      <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-body p-3">
                        <small class="float-right">Дата: {{ $new->created_at }}</small>
                    <a href="{{url('news/'.$new->id)}}" class=""><h2 class="card-title pt-4 black-text">{{ $new->title }}</h2></a>
                    <p class="card-text">{{ $new->title_small }}<a href="{{url('news/'.$new->id)}}" class=""> ...читать далее</a></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    @break

    @case(2)
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card mb-4 news-block-small">
          <div class="view overlay zoom">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="{{URL::asset($new->img_main)}}" alt="Card image cap">
            <a href="{{url('news/'.$new->id)}}">
              <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body p-3">
                <small class="float-right">Дата: {{ $new->created_at }}</small>
            <a href="{{url('news/'.$new->id)}}" class=""><h2 class="card-title pt-4 black-text">{{ $new->title }}</h2></a>
            <p class="card-text">{{ $new->title_small }}<a href="{{url('news/'.$new->id)}}" class=""> ...читать далее</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    @break
</div>
@endswitch

@if ($k >= 2)
    @php
        $k = 0;
    @endphp
@else
    @php
        $k++;
    @endphp
@endif

@endforeach
<div class="offset-5">
    {{ $news->links() }}
</div>
```

Comment: С макетом совпадает? Поскольку это bootstrap попробуй вынести открывающие и закрывающие теги `<div class="row"> </div>` за цикл foreach. Внутри цикла только колонки.